# How do I override autogenerated accessors in Perl's Class::DBI?

Tags: perl, class-dbi

I followed the example at http://wiki.class-dbi.com/wiki/Overriding_autogenerated_accessors

I want to modify the URL before it is inserted to the database:

```
package Hosting::Company;
use base 'Class::DBI';

 my $class = __PACKAGE__;

$class->table('Companies');
$class->columns(Primary => 'CompanyId');
$class->columns(Others => qw/Name Url Comment/);

sub Url {
my $self = shift;

    # modify URL.
    if (@_) {
        $_[0] = 'aaaaaaaaaaaa';
        # return $self->_Url_accessor('aaaaaaaaaaaa'); - doesn't work either
    }

    # Back to normal Class::DBI 
    return $self->_Url_accessor(@_);
}
```

But it doesn't work:

```
my $company = Hosting::Company->insert({ Name => 'Test', Url => 'http://http://url' });
print $company->Url, "\n";
```

Shows:

```
http://http://url
```

I wish the Class:DBI mailing list were still alive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding an accessor does not change `insert`.  The best way to handle data normalization is to override [`normalize_column_values()`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::DBI#DATA_NORMALIZATION).  But Manni is right, your accessor is busted.

PS  The [CDBI mailing list](http://lists.digitalcraftsmen.net/mailman/listinfo/classdbi) is still active, just hasn't seen much posting.  Most have moved on to [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class).

Answer (score 3):

In you URL accessor, you check whether a parameter was passed to that method. But you aren't passing anyhting in so the accessor will do nothing but call _Url_accessor(). You should probably call _Url_accessor first and then modify the result:

```
sub Url {
    my $self = shift;

    # Was there a param passed in?
    if ( @_ ) {
         # Do you really want to modify it here?
         return $self->_Url_accessor(@_);
    }
    else {
        my $url = $self->_Url_accessor();
        # mangle result here:
        $url = 'aaaaaaaaa';
        return $url;
     }
}
```

If you want to change the URL before it even goes in the database, I guess you must provide a normalize_column_values in your class and this will be called each time an insert is made.

Comment: I think you mean `return $self->_Url_accessor(@_);` and `my $url = $self->_Url_accessor();`

Comment: I removed the downvote.  You're right about the OP's accessor override being busted.  I thought it was only due to the insert-doesn't-use-accessors issue.